# Create domain partition with Dapper FastCrud ModelGenerator

Tags: dapper, dapper-fastcrud

Our Sql Server database has multiple schemas/owners. Some of the table names are identical without the schema so when configuring the Model Generator I would like to be able to either filter by schema or append the schema name to the table so there is no conflict. I have tried filtering by table prefix but that only seems to work on the table name.

```
Schema1.Companies
Schema2.Companies
```

I would like the Model Generator to produce either this

```
namespace models
    [Table("Schema1Companies")]
    [Table("Schema2Companies")]
```

or this

```
namespace models.Schema1
    [Table("Companies")]

namespace models.Schema2
    [Table("Companies")]
```

https://github.com/MoonStorm/Dapper.FastCRUD/wiki/Entity-registration

Answer (score 0):

Digging around the code a little I found the `SchemaName` variable. So I can create a `ModelGeneratorConfig` file for each schema with it's own namespace.